# how to connect to mongodb remotely

Tags: 18.04, database, mongodb

How can I remotely access my mongodb database using compass? I have followed the instructions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04), but compass cannot connect and shows me `connect ECONNREFUSED MY_SERVER_IP:27017`. What is missing or wrong? thanks

Answer (score 0):

1)Disable your firewall 
  In ubuntu 
  -->ufw disable

In centos 
  -->systemctl stop firewalld.service
2) Change mongod.conf
 --> change bindIp: 0.0.0.0